# Insert the hyperlinks source in mysql table by clicking it

Tags: php, html

```
<a href=abc.html name="text1">click me </a>
```

I have to send abc.html into a table in my database when I click the link

Comment: There are several ways to do so. You should provide some more information, e.g. is the website supposed to be opened and if so, is it fine if the html actually contained php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of achieving what you are trying to do.
I think though the "cleanest" would be to use jquery (javascript) to manipulate the event handler.

Something like this would work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a href="abc.html">click me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href"); // Here we retrieve the href of clicked link
    var res = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            url: url // The left side is the request key ( so: $_POST['url'])
        },
        url: "https://url/to/handler.php",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    console.log(res);
    if(res == "success") return true; // returning true lets the browser follow the link
    else return false; /* so if it didn't work, the link will not be
                          followed. Of course you can do at these two
                          points whatever you like. */
  })
});
</script>
```

Simply echo in PHP success if the insert was successful.

Note though that async:false for AJAX requests is deprecated.